# Reverse log transformation on data frame

Tags: r

Sorry for the basic question, but I have been wasting a lot of time trying to reverse the log transformation on a data frame.
I have a data frame ( 29123 x 5250 ) whose values are log2 transformed. I want to reverse this to get normal non-logarithmic values.

I tried something like this :

```
apply(dataset, 2, function(x)  {
  2^x 
})
```

But this gives me the following error :

> `Error in 2^x : non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Please help me understand how I can get this to work.

Thanks !

Comment: Your data contains non numeric columns, adding few records here in the question will help understand more

Answer (score 1):

You get the error message when you apply a mathematical operation to a value which is not a number. For example :

```
2^'a'
```

> Error in 2^"a" : non-numeric argument to binary operator

You need to apply this function to only numeric columns in your data. Also `^` can be directly applied to dataframe, no need for `apply`. Consider this example.

```
df <- data.frame(a = letters[1:3], b = 1:3, c = 4:6)
cols <- sapply(df, is.numeric)
df[cols] <- 2^df[cols]
df

#  a b  c
#1 a 2 16
#2 b 4 32
#3 c 8 64
```